# Coffeescript creating a button that creates text when clicked

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, getelementbyid

```
window.onload = ->
  document.write ('<h1 id="begin">Begin</h1>')

  document.getElementById("begin").onClick = -> 
    document.write ('Do you go left or right?')
```

Using coffeescript to try making a small game book for practice. I'm having trouble already... I can't seem get this button to work and have no clue what I'm doing wrong. My code creates the "begin" text just fine, but when it's clicked nothing happens. The console log isn't throwing any errors...

http://codepen.io/bryanwillis7/pen/WwMPaw

Here's my codepen to see the compiled javascript. I don't think it's a coffeescript error though...

Comment: It isn't `onClick`, but `onclick`.

Comment: Don't leave a space between the function name and the opening parenthesis when using function-calling parentheses in CoffeeScript; `f (x)` is fine by accident but `f (x, y)` is a syntax error.

Comment: @mu is too short 

Thank you so much! I didn't know that! I'll definitely make sure to remove those spaces from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ismael Miguel stated, when you click 'Begin' the text isn't printing because `document.getElementById("begin").onClick` should be `document.getElementById("begin").onclick` instead:

```
window.onload = ->
  document.write ('<h1 id="begin">Begin</h1>')

  document.getElementById("begin").onclick = -> 
  document.write ('Do you go left or right?')
```

Comment: (1) `f (x)` only works by accident, you want `f(x)` for those `write` calls. (2) You left out the indentation before the second `document.write` and that changes the meaning of the code.

Comment: Yeah, surprisingly my mistake was as simple as .onClick being changed to .onclick  However, Mu is right in that the indentation is important for me to maintain.

Thanks so much for the swift responses. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  document.getElementById("begin").addEventListener "click", () => document.write ('Do you go left or right?')
```